# How do I get DOM element bound to specific object in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array, bound to the list of contenteditable divs. I have an 'add' button. On click I add an object to array and want to give focus to the corresponding div.

```
<ul id='list' data-bind="foreach: array">
  <li>
    <div contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: $data.text"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="add">+</div>
```

javascript

```
var viewModel = {
  array: ko.observableArray([])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('list'));

document.getElementById('add').onclick = function (evt) {
  var newObject = {text : ''};
  viewModel.array.push(newObject);
  // give focus to the newly created div
};
```

It is possible to get the observable data having DOM element `ko.dataFor(dom)`. How to get DOM by data?

http://jsfiddle.net/5rxdZ/

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get the DOM element from the data itself.  In this scenario though, you could use the `hasfocus` binding to move focus to the new element. Docs here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html

Even just placing `hasfocus: true` on a new element will do the trick.

Otherwise, if you don't want the focus to be applied for the initially rendered elements, then you could pass in a flag for the newly created element like:

```
<ul id='list' data-bind="foreach: array">
  <li>
    <div contenteditable="true" data-bind="hasfocus: $data.focused, text: $data.text"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="add">+</div>
```

view model:

```
var newObject = {text : '', focused: true};
viewModel.array.push(newObject);
```

Sample:  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/jnHK8/

Comment: thank you. though it's quite frustrating that i can get data by dom, but not vice versa